# Difference between tex.fmt and plain.fmt in TeX Live

Tags: texlive, installing

My setup: TeX Live, version 2014.20141024-2 (packaged with Debian 8 Jessie)

In `man tex` it's written:

> ... when called as tex the tex format is used, which is identical to the plain format ...

If this is so, why greeting differs in following two commands ? (TeXk instead of TeX; and \write18 added)

```
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (preloaded format=tex)
**
```

```
$ initex '\input plain \dump'
$ tex -fmt plain
This is TeXk, Version 3.14159265 (preloaded format=plain)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

Also, I need to override default tex.fmt with local tex.fmt, created from plain.tex:

I put new tex.fmt to /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/, then run texhash on it.
`kpsewhich tex.fmt` gives `/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/tex.fmt`, as expected.

But when I run 'tex', it uses default tex.fmt
How to override it?
**EDIT:** put new tex.fmt to /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/tex/, and it will work.

Comment: Are you really using TeX Live 2015? TeX Live 2014 isn't even frozen yet.

Comment: @cfr: I'm using texlive packages that come with Debian 8 Jessie

Comment: Which are not TeX Live 2015, I suspect....

Comment: @cfr: I removed this part.

Comment: Why don't you post the actual output?

Comment: @Igor: (1) If the program name is `tex`, most extensions such as
`parse_first_line`
are disabled by default. In this case the banner is
`This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 ...`
In the case of `tex --fmt=plain ...`, the program name
is reset to `plain`, thus some extensions are enabled,
so the banner changes into
`This is TeXk, Version 3.14159265 ...`
If you type
`tex --progname=tex --fmt=plain ...`,
the banner is again
`This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 ...`.
(2) format files are searched in the following order:
`current directory`, `$TEXMF/web2c/$engine`, `$TEXMF/web2c`.

Comment: @Akira: 1) is worth writing in the answer. 2) I found the solution (see EDIT).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tex.fmt is created by

```
\input plain
\dump
\endinput
```

Thus it is the same as your plain.fmt.
In the present implementation of TeX, the banner

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 ...
```

is printed only when the TeX is nearly equal to
the original TeX by Knuth. This is discriminated by the
program name 'tex'.
In the case of

```
tex --fmt=plain ...
```

the program name is reset to

```
plain
```

so, some extensions such as

```
parse_first_line
```

are enabled. In this case the banner becomes

```
This is TeXk, Version 3.14159265 ...
```

If you type

```
tex --progname=tex --fmt=plain ...
```

then the banner is again

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 ...
```